# Can I change my public site collection into a 'normal' site collection?

Tags: site-collection, feature, site, feature-activation, public-website

My xxxx-public.sharepoint.com has very limited features compared to my other site collections that are not public. I have spent a while working on the public website but now I need access to features that are not enabled on it. I would like to change it back into a 'normal'site collection. Is there any way I can do this quickly without losing all my hard work? I am not a power-user / coder and dont have access to powe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their is no OOTB way to convert the Public site into team site as both using the different template.

Now two things you can do.

1. Create a team site and move all the content manually
2. Use the 3rd party tool to convert it. you can try Sharegate, Metalogix.